# Python input array one line

Tags: python, arrays

I want to be able to input something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and have it return another array like ['a'. 'b', 'c'] How do I do this?
I have tried this but I can only do single numbers.

```
 arr = list(map(int, input("message > ").split()))
```

Comment: How would you do it not on one line? I have not idea how 1-7 turns into a-c, so perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: actually `chr(1)` returns A , i.e. as capital letter; but I don't think that's what you mean either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.ascii_lowercase` - which is a string of lowercased letters - along with a `list` comprehension as shown below.

To handle the case of multi-digit numbers, you'll need to separate the numbers in the input, for example using a space   character, and then split on this character when processing the user input.

```py
import string

arr = [string.ascii_lowercase[int(i) - 1]
       for i in input("message > ").split(' ')]

print(arr)
```

Sample interaction with user:

```
message > 1 3 5 7 9 11
['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k']
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, I think he wants different arrays not actually 'a', 'b', etc.

Comment: well, unless I misunderstood wrong, I think it seems to answer it. I'm quoting from OP, correct me if I'm misinterpreting: *"have it return another array like ['a'. 'b', 'c']"*

Comment: FWIW: I was about to post something *very* similar. This is how I understood the question too.

Comment: @rv.kvetch you may be right because the question is unclear but it doesn't make sense to want to turn 1 into 'a' etc. in this case because you could just enter a instead. But again it needs clarification.

Comment: yeah agreed, converting a number to a letter doesn't make much sense, but definitely some clarification would help out.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you would like to make multiple lists inside a list from a single input.

If you know how many arrays you want you can use:

```
arr = [list(map(int, input("message > ").split())) for _ in range(3)]
```

Output:

```
message > 1 2 3
message > 1 4 5
message > 1 3 4
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4]]
```

if you don't know how many you could use:

```
arr = [[i] for i in list(input("message > ").split(","))]
```

Output:

```
message > 1 2 3, 1 4 5, 1 3 4
[['1 2 3'], [' 1 4 5'], [' 1 3 4']]
```

In the second just separate the inputs with commas.

Comment: yes but I want to input it with square brackets and commas

Comment: How do you mean? @TheGoose